# Issue while storing data to Influxdb using telegragh configuration with custom timestamp

Tags: telegraf, influxdb-2, telegraf-plugins

I am trying to implement a small datalogger using Influxdb v2.7, Telegraf v1.26, and Grafana v9.4.
The data is in JSON format and it is fetched from the mosquitto mqtt server using Telegraf.
I am trying to store data with a custom timestamp given in the JSON object .

The JSON data which Telegraf receives from the MQTT server is as given below:-

```
{
 "time": "2006-01-02 15:04:05",
 "data":123,
 "temp1":50.23,
 "temp2":150.23
}
```

this data was not logged in the database which I checked on Influxdb UI.

when I intentionally entered the wrong month in the above JSON data, it showed the following error:

```
Error in the plugin: parsing time "2006-55-02 15:04:05": month out of range
```

and no error when I sent data in the correct format.
From this, I believe Telegraf is processing data and timestamp but perhaps not passed to DB.

Also, when I commented following 2 lines in the Telegraf configuration, it worked and I could see data being logged to Influxdb.

```
 json_time_key = "time"
 json_time_format = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
```

I have made sure that the time format mentioned in Telegraf and the sent data is matching.

I need to store all the above parameters in separate tags. I have given below my telegraph config. please let me know how this issue can be resolved.
Thank you in Advance

```
# Configuration for telegraf agent
[agent]
  ## Default data collection interval for all inputs
  interval = "10s"
  ## Rounds collection interval to 'interval'
  ## ie, if interval="10s" then always collect on :00, :10, :20, etc.
  round_interval = true

  ## Telegraf will send metrics to outputs in batches of at most
  ## metric_batch_size metrics.
  ## This controls the size of writes that Telegraf sends to output plugins.
  metric_batch_size = 1000

  ## Maximum number of unwritten metrics per output.  Increasing this value
  ## allows for longer periods of output downtime without dropping metrics at the
  ## cost of higher maximum memory usage.
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000

  ## Collection jitter is used to jitter the collection by a random amount.
  ## Each plugin will sleep for a random time within jitter before collecting.
  ## This can be used to avoid many plugins querying things like sysfs at the
  ## same time, which can have a measurable effect on the system.
  collection_jitter = "0s"

  ## Default flushing interval for all outputs. Maximum flush_interval will be
  ## flush_interval + flush_jitter
  flush_interval = "10s"
  ## Jitter the flush interval by a random amount. This is primarily to avoid
  ## large write spikes for users running a large number of telegraf instances.
  ## ie, a jitter of 5s and interval 10s means flushes will happen every 10-15s
  flush_jitter = "0s"

  ## By default or when set to "0s", precision will be set to the same
  ## timestamp order as the collection interval, with the maximum being 1s.
  ##   ie, when interval = "10s", precision will be "1s"
  ##       when interval = "250ms", precision will be "1ms"
  ## Precision will NOT be used for service inputs. It is up to each individual
  ## service input to set the timestamp at the appropriate precision.
  ## Valid time units are "ns", "us" (or "µs"), "ms", "s".
  precision = ""

  ## Log at debug level.
  # debug = false
  ## Log only error level messages.
  # quiet = false

  ## Log target controls the destination for logs and can be one of "file",
  ## "stderr" or, on Windows, "eventlog".  When set to "file", the output file
  ## is determined by the "logfile" setting.
  # logtarget = "file"

  ## Name of the file to be logged to when using the "file" logtarget.  If set to
  ## the empty string then logs are written to stderr.
  # logfile = ""

  ## The logfile will be rotated after the time interval specified.  When set
  ## to 0 no time based rotation is performed.  Logs are rotated only when
  ## written to, if there is no log activity rotation may be delayed.
  # logfile_rotation_interval = "0d"

  ## The logfile will be rotated when it becomes larger than the specified
  ## size.  When set to 0 no size based rotation is performed.
  # logfile_rotation_max_size = "0MB"

  ## Maximum number of rotated archives to keep, any older logs are deleted.
  ## If set to -1, no archives are removed.
  # logfile_rotation_max_archives = 5

  ## Pick a timezone to use when logging or type 'local' for local time.
  ## Example: America/Chicago
  # log_with_timezone = ""

  ## Override default hostname, if empty use os.Hostname()
  hostname = ""
  ## If set to true, do no set the "host" tag in the telegraf agent.
  omit_hostname = false
[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  ## The URLs of the InfluxDB cluster nodes.
  ##
  ## Multiple URLs can be specified for a single cluster, only ONE of the
  ## urls will be written to each interval.
  ##   ex: urls = ["https://us-west-2-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com"]
  urls = ["http://192.168.1.111:8086"]

  ## Token for authentication.
  token = "token"

  ## Organization is the name of the organization you wish to write to; must exist.
  organization = "test"

  ## Destination bucket to write into.
  bucket = "Datalogger1"

  ## The value of this tag will be used to determine the bucket.  If this
  ## tag is not set the 'bucket' option is used as the default.
  # bucket_tag = ""

  ## If true, the bucket tag will not be added to the metric.
  # exclude_bucket_tag = false

  ## Timeout for HTTP messages.
  # timeout = "5s"

  ## Additional HTTP headers
  # http_headers = {"X-Special-Header" = "Special-Value"}

  ## HTTP Proxy override, if unset values the standard proxy environment
  ## variables are consulted to determine which proxy, if any, should be used.
  # http_proxy = "http://corporate.proxy:3128"

  ## HTTP User-Agent
  # user_agent = "telegraf"

  ## Content-Encoding for write request body, can be set to "gzip" to
  ## compress body or "identity" to apply no encoding.
  # content_encoding = "gzip"

  ## Enable or disable uint support for writing uints influxdb 2.0.
  # influx_uint_support = false

  ## Optional TLS Config for use on HTTP connections.
  # tls_ca = "/etc/telegraf/ca.pem"
  # tls_cert = "/etc/telegraf/cert.pem"
  # tls_key = "/etc/telegraf/key.pem"
  ## Use TLS but skip chain & host verification
  # insecure_skip_verify = false
# Read metrics from MQTT topic(s)
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  ## Broker URLs for the MQTT server or cluster.  To connect to multiple
  ## clusters or standalone servers, use a separate plugin instance.
  ##   example: servers = ["tcp://localhost:1883"]
  ##            servers = ["ssl://localhost:1883"]
  ##            servers = ["ws://localhost:1883"]
  servers = ["mqtt://192.168.1.111:1883"]

  ## Topics that will be subscribed to.
  topics = [
    "telegraf/host01/cpu",
    "telegraf/+/mem",
    "test/Sensor/#",
  ]

  ## The message topic will be stored in a tag specified by this value.  If set
  ## to the empty string no topic tag will be created.
  # topic_tag = "topic"

  ## QoS policy for messages
  ##   0 = at most once
  ##   1 = at least once
  ##   2 = exactly once
  ##
  ## When using a QoS of 1 or 2, you should enable persistent_session to allow
  ## resuming unacknowledged messages.
   qos = 0

  ## Connection timeout for initial connection in seconds
   connection_timeout = "60s"

  ## Maximum messages to read from the broker that have not been written by an
  ## output.  For best throughput set based on the number of metrics within
  ## each message and the size of the output's metric_batch_size.
  ##
  ## For example, if each message from the queue contains 10 metrics and the
  ## output metric_batch_size is 1000, setting this to 100 will ensure that a
  ## full batch is collected and the write is triggered immediately without
  ## waiting until the next flush_interval.
  # max_undelivered_messages = 1000

  ## Persistent session disables clearing of the client session on connection.
  ## In order for this option to work you must also set client_id to identify
  ## the client.  To receive messages that arrived while the client is offline,
  ## also set the qos option to 1 or 2 and don't forget to also set the QoS when
  ## publishing.
  # persistent_session = false

  ## If unset, a random client ID will be generated.
  # client_id = ""

  ## Username and password to connect MQTT server.
   username = "user1"
   password = "password123"

  ## Optional TLS Config
  # tls_ca = "/etc/telegraf/ca.pem"
  # tls_cert = "/etc/telegraf/cert.pem"
  # tls_key = "/etc/telegraf/key.pem"
  ## Use TLS but skip chain & host verification
  # insecure_skip_verify = false

  ## Data format to consume.
  ## Each data format has its own unique set of configuration options, read
  ## more about them here:
  ## https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/DATA_FORMATS_INPUT.md
 
data_format = "json"
  ## Time key is the key containing the time that should be used to create the
  ## metric.
 
  json_time_key = "time"
  json_time_format = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"

  ## Enable extracting tag values from MQTT topics
  ## _ denotes an ignored entry in the topic path
  # [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.topic_parsing]]
  #   topic = ""
  #   measurement = ""
  #   tags =[""]
  #   fields = ""
  ## Value supported is int, float, unit
  #   [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.topic.types]]
  #      key = type
```